# express-session won't persist and won't send a cookie to the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, express-session

I am working on a mern stack (react, node, express & mongodb) web app.
I have installed express-session on node.js. however, i don't see a connect.sid cookie in the browser. also, it seems that the session does not persist between requests in node.

I initially thought that this was a cors problem (which could still be the case) so I tried some tweaking on the CORS headers, but without any luck.

```
//this is the main app.js file in node.js

var session = require('express-session')

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    );
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
        return res.status(200).json({});
    }
    next();
});

app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false }
}));
```

```
//this is the index.js route file in node.js

router.get('/check_if_session_exists_when_refreshing', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.json(req.session)
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});

router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
  UserModel.findOne({ username: req.body.username }).then((data) => {
    bcrypt.compare(req.body.password.toString(), data.password.toString()).then((resp, err) => {
      if (resp) {
        req.session.user = {
          username: req.body.username,
          password: req.body.password
        }
        res.json([data])
      }
      else console.log(err)
    })
  });
});
```

```
// this is the React-Redux login action on the client side
import { FETCH_USER } from './types';

export const fetchUser = (userData) => dispatch => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(userData)
    }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(user =>
            dispatch({
                type: FETCH_USER,
                payload: user
            })
        );
};
```

The expected result: A persisting session id on the express framework and a cookie file stored in the browser.

The actual result: Session does not persist and cookie is not stored.

Comment: update: i still haven't fixed this issue, I just noticed the I am getting a session cookie with postman but not with the browser.

Comment: Have u got the solution...I'm stuck right here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIX UPDATE:
the problem was that the credentials init options weren't set on the fetch API.

the correct code should be written like this:

```
// this is the React-Redux login action on the client side

export const fetchUser = (userData) => dispatch => {
fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    credentials: "include",
    body: JSON.stringify(userData)
}).then(response => response.json())
    .then(user =>
        dispatch({
            type: FETCH_USER,
            payload: user
        })
    );
};
```

also, in the CORS settings, a wildcard ('*') cannot be used as the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'. Instead, it needs the origin address which in my case was http://localhost:3001.

```
//this is the main app.js file in node.js

app.use((req, res, next) => {
res.header('Access-control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3001');
res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
);
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET');
    return res.status(200).json({});
}
next();
});
```

In retrospect, I have already figured this out in a relatively early stage. but unbeknownst to me, resetting nodemon wasen't enough after making those changes.
**a manual server shutdown was needed for the changes to take place.**